# bash output to /dev/null is 100x faster than stdout

Tags: bash, stdout, dev-null

The following simple program is `100x` faster when directed to `/dev/null`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (int i=0;i<10000000;i++) { printf("%d\n",i); }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I find where *exactly* the speedup comes from?

```
$ gcc -O0 main.c -o main
$ ./main
$ ./main >/dev/null
$ ./main > output.txt
```

**EDIT**:
redirecting to a file is `100x` faster too.
so I guess `/dev/null` is *exactly* like any other file?

Comment: What about output to a file?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:bash]? Also, why do you compile with `-O0` if you want something to be as fast as possible?

Comment: @DaBler I'll add that to the post ... it's 100x faster too

Comment: I compiled with `-O0` to make sure that this whole loop will not disappear into thin air ...

Comment: @OrenIshShalom The compiler isn't allowed to make it disappear into thin air because that would change observable effects of the program.

Comment: I guess a better question is: `is redirection to /dev/null the same as redirection to an arbitrary file` ...

Comment: @OrenIshShalom Yes, it is after all a [device file](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#Character_devices)

Comment: printing 10 million lines to stdout is always going to be slow; think about what has to be done to print a line to a 'window', redrawing the window to shift lines up, etc, etc, etc ... **tons** of time to do that for 10 million iterations; minimizing the window may help speed up the process, some, but the console is still having to process/display 10 million lines of output; all of this overhead to 'display' 10 million lines goes away when writing to a file (or /dev/null)

Comment: Other "arbitrary" files involve synchronizing with whichever medium you are writing to; if it is slower than your write rate, you will be blocking to wait for the I/O buffers to clear. With `/dev/null` obviously the output buffer will be instantaneously cleared.

Answer (score 2):

Uh, because printing to the terminal is slow? Try it over a 300 baud connection!

Comment: I mean to ask in what ways the resource (is it really?) `/dev/null` different than the terminal resource? specifically, does it need to be "locked" for access?

Comment: No, there is no need to lock it. It would be silly to attempt to impose integrity checks for data you are throwing away.

Comment: _baud_ Now that's a blast from the past. :D